# How to get mean of matrix columns for a column of matrices inside dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matrix

I have a dataframe with two columns. The first column has the class number (either 1 or 0). The second column holds matrices that are (1999,13). I am trying to figure out how to convert the matrices to (1,13) by getting the mean of each matrix column.

The reason I am doing this is for audio processing. I extracted the MFCCs for each 10 second audio file I have. For each 10 second audio there are 1999 frames, and each frame has 13 cepstral coefficients.

```py
example_df = pd.DataFrame()
example_df['Class'] = [1,0,0]
example_df['MFCCs'] =[np.random.rand(4,2),np.random.rand(4,2),np.random.rand(4,2)]
example_df
```

when I apply np.mean I am almost always getting the mean of the class as well which is about 0.5, even if I indicate the 'MFCCs' column.

The expected output should be something like

```
   Class  MFCCs
0  1      [C01,C02]
1  0      [C11,C12]
2  0      [C21,C22]
```

Comment: Your 'MFCCs' column is object dtype, that is, it stores each of the (4,2) arrays as an object in the cell.  `example_df['MFCCs'].to_numpy()` will a be an object dtype array.  Applying `np.stack` to that might work and produce a `(n,4,2)` array.

Comment: @hpaulj I know that np.stack just stacks arrays on top of each other, but I am not sure how this helps me in this situation

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.mean and specify the axis across which you want to take the mean, in your case axis=0. For example:

```
a = np.arange(8).reshape(4,2)
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])

np.mean(a,axis=0)
array([3., 4.])
```

For your purpose you can do it on one line :

```
arrays = [np.random.rand(4,2),np.random.rand(4,2),np.random.rand(4,2)]
example_df['MFCCs'] =[np.mean(a,axis=0) for a in arrays]
```

Comment: Yes this works for the example I put above. However, I don't have the 'arrays' attribute. What I am trying to say is the way my df was constructed wasn't as straightforward as the example. However, the df produced in the example resembles my actual df but a much smaller scale of course. I am hoping there is another method

Comment: I tried doing arrays = df['MFCC'], followed by df['MFCC'] =[np.mean(a,axis=0) for a in arrays] and what happened was there was just one number in the MFCC column for every row rather than an array of 13 numbers

Comment: If you apply example_df['MFCCs'].values you get a numpy array of the column. Print the shape of the numpy array that you get from example_df['MFCCs'].values, maybe it clarifies

Comment: Nevermind, for the past 30 mins I have been rerunning the code but added an np.mean before adding each matrix to the dataframe and that worked... Thanks regardless!